# set minimum height in VerticalSplitPanel of GWT

Tags: gwt, resize, scroll, vertical-scrolling, splitter

I am using VerticalSplitPanel to split two panel. I want to set the minimum allowable size for the given widget.

Its associated splitter cannot be dragged to a position that would make it smaller than this size.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This panel is deprecated. Use SplitLayoutPanel instead.

Use .setWidgetMinSize() to set the minimum width of a child widget.